# How to set an Image to top right corner of a form heading

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I’m using eclipse rcp forms ,

I'm  trying to set an Image using

```
form.setImage()
```

merely it sets image to the left of form text. How can i place an image towards top right corner of the form title text.

As shown in below pic(image is the default overview tab of any RCP application) 
 [image]

From the above pic I understand that the images/widgets are placed beside the Form text(apologies if I’m wrong).

As a workaround I tried placing a composite in the form head, but I believe that form head comes after form title level(if we consider form title as 1st row, then form head appears as 2nd row)

```
Composite composite = formToolkit.createComposite(form.getHead(), SWT.NONE);
form.setHeadClient(composite);
formToolkit.paintBordersFor(composite);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
```

In this fashion i attempted to place components to the composite but anyways I don't get the desired style as shown in the image.

How to place an image to the top right of the form title

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set images to the right corner. What you see in the attached image is a toolbar with some `IContributionItem`'s

To create something you have to override `org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.SharedHeaderFormEditor.createHeaderContents(IManagedForm)` with something like the following:

```java
@Override
protected void createHeaderContents(final IManagedForm headerForm) {

    headerForm.getForm().setText("EditorTitle");
    headerForm.getForm().setImage(myLeftImage);
    headerForm.getToolkit().decorateFormHeading(
            headerForm2.getForm().getForm());
    Action action = new Action("Do something") {
        @Override
        public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor() {
            return imageDescriptorOfRightImage;
        }
    };
    headerForm.getForm().getToolBarManager().add(action);
    headerForm.getForm().getToolBarManager().update(true);

}
```